# Is there a way to solve EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am facing this problem and I have tried a lot of solutions to fix it yet nothing seem to work: `yarn cache clean` and I deleted yarn and reinstalled it again then tried to reinstall nodejs and npm.

Yarn Error: When I run yarn install this error pops out:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'C:\Users\MYCOM\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-request-2.88.2-d73c918731cb5a87da047e207234146f664d12b3-integrity\node_modules\request\lib\cookies.js' -> 'D:\v-location\v-location-server\node_modules\request\lib\cookies.js'".

Yet when I run npm install every thing works fine and all dependencies are installed can anyone help me fix it or at least till me the reason of this error?

This is what notepad++ gives me when I open any coockies.js file available in my pc

[image: This is what notepad++ gives me when I open any coockies.js file available in my pc]

Comment: Does the path D:\v-location\v-location-server\node_modules\request\lib exist?  Do you have permission to write cookies.js in that location?

Comment: Yes it does exist and yes i am able to write to it. :(

Comment: nodepad++ shouldn't care about the contents of the file.  I would check your file system for corruption (`chkdsk d: /f`?)

Comment: I run the command you gave me and it showed this: Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

Answer (score 0):

Set the yarn cache directory to other disk, such as:

```
yarn config set cache-folder 'D:/yarn-cache'
```